# Can I charge my phone with a very low amp?

Tags: telephone

I am working on a charging device for a smartphone, it's for a science project, Currently I finished planning all the electronic parts for it and I am getting ready to start building, however I noticed something, after calculations I found out that my new charger will give an output of 5v and 0~0.02 amp, now my question is: will this electricity of 5v and 0.02 amp enough to start charging the phone? I don't really care at this moment about the charging speed, because when presenting it I will just need to show that it starts charging my device, I won't be demonstrating the charging speed, so even if it takes a year to charge that ain't my concern right now. My concern is: will it trigger the phone to charge or not?

Comment: Limit a bench power supply to 20mA at 5V and try it out. Probably varies wildly depending on the phone.

Comment: In order to charge the battery, your supply needs to deliver enough current to operate the phone AND have some left over to put into the battery. Will 20mA be enough? I'd say it's unlikely.

Comment: @Finbarr Is it always the case? I remember some crappy car charger I had. It allowed the phone to run for a bit longer, while the battery was still drained. And I suspect it killed my battery after all...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Providing a bit of extra power to reduce the drain on the battery is not the same as charging it. The question asks about charging the battery and that can only happen if the phone itself is running from the external supply.

Comment: @Finbarr I mean the OP might be interested only in getting the "charging" icon/led to show up. Not really to actually charge.

Comment: Yes I am just interested into turning on that charging L.E.D. on the top of my phone and get the charging icon on the status bar, not really interested if it actually charges it slowly, or if it doesn't at all but let the battery drain less quicker, all I want is that charging LED to turn on

Comment: I doubt that the phone will turn on the charging LED or screen symbol unless it is *actually* charging the battery. It's not just a power indicator.

Comment: Ok, so it seems there is no need to build that circuit, it will be a waste of time. Can you please help me?

Comment: I need a step up dc-dc converter that step-up will convert from 1.5 v coming from a DC generator to 5v that is acceptable by the phone.

Comment: The only help I can offer is to follow the suggestion from @WesleyLee and try it with a bench supply.

Comment: Show us the calculations that told you that your supply would only output 20mA at 5V.

Comment: Well the circuit was originally designed for a 200mA and 1.5 INPUT, and would give an OUTPUT of: 160mA and 6.7v however while getting ready to build I found that my INPUT is: 20mA and 1.5~2 volts so i used the same efficiency squall I think It will be around 10~20mA and 4.7~5.1v

Comment: 300mW in and 1072mW out. Sorry, that's not physically possible.

Comment: I meant 2A and 1.5v as INPUT and an OUTPUT of: 167mA and 5.1v for the original plan and what I got now is an INPUT of: 20mA and 1.5v and OUTPUT of N/A, I guess you understand my problem now

Comment: Sorry for the typo

Comment: Don't forget about the USB D+/D- connections to signal to the phone to enter charging mode (it that's the case), otherwise not even with a proper supply it will charge.

Comment: "I guess you understand my problem now" No, I'm now completely lost. You clearly are, too.

Comment: Yes I am, my original design for my step up converter was designed to get 2A and 1.5v as INPUT and give an OUTPUT of: 167mA and 5.1v and because of a small problem I got to use a new source of input now I got an INPUT of: 20mA and 1.5v and OUTPUT of (I don't know). My problem is I will need to sacrifice ampere to get voltage which is needed for the phone to trigger the charging LED that ampere I will sacrifice will get as near if not equal to 0 what I said in the question: it should be around 0~20mA, now that is what I want to know: is that near to 0 current with 5v enough to trigger the phone

Comment: Looks like whatever bit of software or web site you're using to do your calculations is saying that an input of 1.5V at 20mA is not sufficient to run the converter. Even if it was 90% efficient you would only get 5.4mA at 5V out and I can pretty much guarantee that won't turn on your charging indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it will cause a problem with certain phones.  To get around this output current limitation, some "energy harvesting" devices like yours will instead charge an on-board battery at whatever current your source puts out.  Then, when the battery is sufficiently charged, you turn on the charging circuit to the phone.

If you want to learn more about this type of circuit, many manufacturers have developed integrated circuits that take care of a large portion of the difficult part of the circuit.  Usually they go over the theory of operation, and you can learn quite a bit just by reading the datasheets.

Here is a link to an application note involving what I described above:

http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/article/SolarEnergyHarvesting.pdf

If you want to find more information, google the terms "energy harvesting".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to plug it into a bench source with the same voltage/current and see.

The power management in modern phones/computers is a bit more complex than you might think.  In olden times, if you had a battery connected to a light, and added a photocell across it at the same voltage, really all of the current would go to work.  Same for a rechargeable battery.

Nowadays, there is a whole science of the best way to charge and discharge a battery.  And it is all digitally controlled.  So, for instance, the phone may 'reject' too little current, even though it seems all current would help.  Possibly, it determines that more energy gets lost using the extra quantum, or it wants the input to be well/properly conditioned, or the battery to be in a given state, or whatever.